# Prove or disprove the compactness of an operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, laplacian, compactness

Consider $X=L^{2}(0,\pi, \mathbb{R})$.

Let $X_{\frac{1}{2}}$ be the domain of $(\Delta)^\frac{1}{2}$ where $\Delta$ is the laplacien operator.

We define the operator $K:C([0,a],X_{\frac{1}{2}})\longrightarrow X_{\frac{1}{2}}$ by:
$$K(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\beta(x,y)\sin(f^{\prime}(y))dy\quad \text{for}\ f\in C([0,a],X_{\frac{1}{2}})$$
where $\beta$ is $C^{1}$-function on $[0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]$.
I am in the step to construct a compact operator, so i found the operator $K$. I can't prove or disprove the compactness of $K$. Please any idea?

Comment: Please not that it only makes sense to talk about "the" Laplace operator if you specify boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you sir about your reaction. Yeah Actually you are right. I meant the Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: it is non-linear, right? how do you define compactness?

Comment: Fedor Petrov thank you so much for your reaction.

Comment: I meant that K transforms any bounded set to a relatively compact set.